Apparent nonsense coincidence from a second-order linear homogeneous ODE
Suppose $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ solve the second-order linear homogeneous differential equation $$\frac {d^2y}{dt^2}+p(t)\frac {dy}{dt}+q(t)y=0$$ where $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are two given continuous functions in an open interval $I=(\alpha, \beta)$.
The quantity $W[y1, y2](t)=y_1(t)y_2'(t)-y_1'(t)y_2(t)$ is called the Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$; the functions $y_1$ and $y_2$ are said to be linearly dependent if one of these functions is a constant multiple of the other, i. e. if there exist $c_1, c_2\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c_1y_1(t)+c_2y_2(t)=0$ $\forall t\in I$.
It can be proved (see Martin Braun, Differential Equations and Their Applications) that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions of the previous ODE, then $W[y1, y2](t)$ is either identically zero or never zero on $I$, which means that if $W[y1, y2](t_0)=0$ for some $ t_0\in I$, then $W[y1, y2](t)=0$ $\forall t\in I$. Moreover, if such $t_0$ exists, then $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent (without loss of generality, say $y_1(t) = c y_2(t)$ $\forall t\in I$).
Now consider the functions $y_1(t)=e^{\gamma t}$ and $y_2(t)=t^2e^{\gamma t}$. It is easy to check that $W[y1, y2](t)=2te^{2\gamma t}$, so $W[y1, y2](0)=0$, but clearly $W[y1, y2](t)\neq0$ $\forall t \neq 0$. Actually, if you substitute $y_1$ and $y_2$ respectively in the differential equation, you get $$p(t)=-2\gamma-\frac{1}{t}$$ and $$q(t)=\gamma^2+\frac{\gamma}{t}$$ hence the problem is not defined at all for $t=0$.
Thus, the apparent contradiction disappears when noticing that the problem is defined for t $\neq 0$, so $y_1$ and $y_2$ are in fact linearly independent.
Strangely enough, it looks like $p$ and $q$ can be considered to be two-variable functions, i.e. $p=p(t,\gamma)$ and $q=q(t,\gamma)$, so that $p=-\frac{\partial q}{\partial \gamma}$ which does not make any sense to me, but that's part of the beauty and mystery of math. Can you find a meaning for this fact, or is it just a strange coincidence?
